# Why do I need an Activity to use BluetoothAdapter?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

When I started working on a mobile application using Android SDK, I wanted to make a BluetoothService class, which would allow me to connect to a paired device and communicate with it by injecting the service whenever I need to.

However, when I tried to implement the Service, I realised that Android BluetoothAdapter depends on an Activity (aka. an active view). So I gave up the idea of having a Service and implemented the Bluetooth directly in the view.

Although it worked, I still had a problem.

Basically, my application was a remote that could be used to control a specific joint/stepper motor of an articulated arm at a time.

[image: Main activity with buttons to control the articulated arm]

Whenever the user wanted to switch to another joint, they either could use the upper right menu, or press the picture at the top (depicting a picture of the arm) to get to another view, where they could press on the part they wanted to control (directly on the picture). It would then return them to the main activity with the arrow buttons.

However, the fact that the application is switching to another activity means that the previous one was destroyed. As such, it happened that the application would temporarily lose the Bluetooth connection with the other device, whereas using an injectable BluetoothService would have allowed my application to carry it over different activities.

Why do I need an Activity to use BluetoothAdapter?

Comment: What do you mean by "bind BluetoothAdapter to an activity"? can you post an example code? When I look at the code for BluetoothAdapter I don't see anything about it being bound to an Activity https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter()

Comment: While discovery and permissions require an activity, I don't recall that much else does. Once you have your `BluetoothDevice`, the rest can be done in the background IIRC. You would not necessarily need a service, though, unless you needed this stuff to work when your UI is not in the foreground. But, in general, questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not suitable for Stack Overflow. Only Developer X can answer the question, and Developer X is unlikely to see the question. Everyone else can only offer opinions.

Comment: FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.12/Bluetooth/RxEcho) demonstrates using Bluetooth both from an activity and from a service. The activity can be used to either start the service or communicate with the service from another copy of the app, running on another Android device.

Comment: @TylerV My bad, the class itself isn't bound to activities, but what CommonsWare pointed out (device discovery and permission require an activity) was my issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the sample app, and for the information too. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: I changed the last line of your question to avoid the "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" bit. The rest of your question is a reasonable fit for Stack Overflow, so there is no reason to delete it if you do not want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions and discovery require an activity because they require user input. The rest of the Bluetooth APIs should, on the whole, not require an activity. In particular, once you get a `BluetoothDevice`, the actual Bluetooth I/O should be able to be done without an activity.

In your case, it is not clear that you really need to be doing this work in the background, so a service may not be required. Either:

- Use a single activity for all of this work, using fragments or something to handle the work being triggered by the action bar item; or
- Have the Bluetooth communications be managed by some singleton, perhaps using a variant on the repository pattern, that lives outside of either activity